# wepack-isomorphic-tools vs process.env.BROWSER

Tags: node.js, reactjs, isomorphic-javascript, webpack-isomorphic-tools

I've read about isomorphic app development and I've seen to methods to handle assets loading in server-side.
One is [webpack-isomorphic-tools](https://github.com/halt-hammerzeit/webpack-isomorphic-tools).
The other is this "hack" where you define a plugin in webpack which sets process.env.BROWSER to true, and loads the assets according to that variable. i.e.:

```
if(process.env.BROWSER){
  require('./styles.scss');
}
```

I wanted to know, which is better and why?